# RMagick > ImageMagick // identify not working in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, rmagick, identify

Something I don't really get…

When I do a

```
$ convert file.jpg file2.jpg
```

everything works fine.
It used to work perfectly too with paperclip from within a rails app.

But for a newly deployed rails app (3.2.9) using the same previous gemfile' setups, I now get the wollowing error

```
identify: ipossible to open image `file':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2498.
identify: no delegate to decode this image format `file' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
```

It seems it has to do with some rvm/ruby installs, but I just don't know where to begin

Comment: nope… and i deployed many apps with this setup ! weird.